# Login Form validation in Reactjs : material ui <textfield>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to do login form validation in my react app. I am new to react and I am using Material UI. So I try to enter the data in the login and password fields but I am not able to. Could someone tell me what exactly is the problem? Is it because I declared the data object in state? Following is the code:

```
state = {
    open: false,
    show: null,
    dialogOpen: false,
    buttonDisabled: true,
    data: {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    },
    errors: {}
};


handleChange = e =>
    this.setState({
        data: { ...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    });

onSubmit = () => {
    const errors = this.validate(this.state.data);
    this.setState({ errors });
};

validate = data => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!Validator.isEmail(data.email)) errors.email = "Invalid email";
    if (!data.password) errors.password = "Can't be blank";
    return errors;
};

 const { data, errors } = this.state;
 <Dialog open={this.state.dialogOpen} onClose={this.closeDialog} >
                        <DialogTitle>Login</DialogTitle>
                        <DialogContent>
                            <DialogContentText>
                                Please enter your Login data here
                            </DialogContentText>
                            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <TextField
                                margin="dense"
                                id="email"
                                label="Email Address"
                                className={classes.textField}
                                type="email"
                                value={data.email}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                fullWidth
                            />
                            {errors.email && <InlineError text={errors.email} />}
                            <TextField
                                margin="dense"
                                id="password"
                                label="Password"
                                className={classes.textField}
                                type="password"
                                value={data.password}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                fullWidth
                            />
                            {errors.password && <InlineError text={errors.password} />}
                            <Button
                                className={classes.button}
                                onClick={this.clickLogin}
                                color="primary"
                            >
                                Enter
                            </Button>
                            </form>
                        </DialogContent>
                    </Dialog>
```

Comment: provide if any errors are being displayed in console and also try to provide the exact code if not similar code , here your code seems to be erroneous

Answer (score 1):

the issue that i noticed with your code is that you are targeting name attribute which you didn't create. so make the following adjustment to your code

```
handleChange = e =>
  this.setState({
    data: { ...this.state.data, [e.target.id]: e.target.value }
  });
  onSubmit = () => {
    const errors = this.validate(this.state.data);
    this.setState({ errors });
 };
```

In the above code, i used e.target.id which can be referenced correctly in the textField.